# DTSearch error while deploying on staging

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, dtsearch

I am facing below error when I upload my silverlight application on staging server.

Could not load file or assembly 'dtsearchNetApi2.dll' or one of its dependencies. The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log for more detail. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)

Is there anyone has idea about its dependency.. I tried but not able to make it done. Is it version issue or other?

Comment: do you have include the dtseach.dll ?

Comment: Yes, Included dtsearchNetApi2.dll